# matlab - brightness levels in image

Tags: image, matlab

how can i take off brightness levels of images?
i mean that i have image, and in parts of the images i have brightness, and i wan't to take it off.

tnx, Jim

Comment: What do you mean by "take off" in relation to brightness here ? Do you mean "reduce", or perhaps "measure" ?

Comment: i mean to reduce. i have parts that not realy defined, like a shadow, and i would like to reduce it, so i won't see it.

Answer (score 3):

When learning about image processing, the easiest way is to try it first in an photo manipulation software (Photoshop, gimp), using elementary operations. For your specific problem, I'm guessing you'll want to look at curves manipulation options.

Once you find a general recipe that works well for what you need, and that gives you an image you like, come back and ask a more precise question (eg: how do I implement a curves adjustment algorithm in Matlab)